# Pivot tables in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that looks like the following

```
col a | col b | col c | col d
1     | A     |  3    | 4.5
2     | A     |  4    | 10.3
2     | B     |  5    | 8
```

I want to pivot this table in such a way that `col b` forms the Columns and `col c` and `col d` become the values. So for each value in `col b`, it needs to have two columns for the values in col `c and d`. The pivoted table would look ideally like the one below:

```
  1 | 3 | 4.5  | N/A | N/A
  2 | 4 | 10.3 | 5   | 8
```

I have done this using python-pandas but was looking to do it using SQL.

Comment: I am using it on google-bigquery. That was the reason I tagged it.

Comment: hard to get the overall logic - please extend your example. is it only A and B  for col_b? or it can be any values?

Comment: I have about 8-9 values for col b. So I can hard code it for now.

Comment: does it mean that you expect two columns per value - meaning total up to 17-19 columns?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: On hindsight, I could also ignore col d and do it just for col c. So for 9 values in col b, we need just 9 columns in the pivoted table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and gives you very simple (but wordy) query for two values (A and B as it is in your example) that you can extend to 8-9 values.

```sql
#standardSQL
with `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` as (
  select 1 col_a, 'A' col_b, 3 col_c, 4.5 col_d union all
  select 2, 'A', 4, 10.3 union all
  select 2, 'B', 5, 8 
)
select 
  col_a, 
  min(if(col_b='A', col_c, null)) A_1,
  min(if(col_b='A', col_d, null)) A_2,
  min(if(col_b='B', col_c, null)) B_1,
  min(if(col_b='B', col_d, null)) B_2
from `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` t
group by col_a
```

result is

```sql
col_a   A_1     A_2     B_1     B_2  
1       3       4.5     null    null     
2       4       10.3    5       8.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Let me try this and get back.

Comment: Works perfectly. I can now tweak it to my requirements. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hi, how about a dynamic column solution?